# AngularJS: UI-Router solving routing hash-bang didn't work

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, angular-ui-router, html5mode

I am currently using Angular version 1.6.4.

To solve the `hashbang` issue I was having, where all of my URL's were in this format:

`http://localhost:8885/#/hotels/holiday-inn`

My `app.js` including the router (using `ui-router`):

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'hotelController'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/hotel/:name',
        templateUrl: 'views/hotel.html',
        controller: 'hotelController'
    });
```

My `ui-view` is located in `Index.cshtml` (I've previously had everything in `_Layout.cshtml` but moved everything to `Index.cshtml`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="hotelScheduler">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My Application</title>
    <link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/hotelController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I'm having a **different** problem. If I access `http://localhost:8885/hotel/holiday-inn`, I get a `404`.

Why is this happening?

**Additional troubleshooting:**

If I access `http://localhost:8885/#/hotel/`, it shows `index.html` rather than `views/hotel.html` and changes the address to `http://localhost:8885/#%2Fhotel%2F`. (I understand this is the work of `otherwise` in the routing, but why does it work with a URL with which starts a hashbang?)

I've been asking around and looking online and people suggest the rest is done through C#'s `MapRoute` or Server Side Code.

How would I do this via either option? If I were to do this Server Side, how do I do this via ASP.Net Core and Visual Studio?

Here's my current `MapRoute`:

```
app.UseMvc(config =>
{
    config.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
    );
});
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**: Based on commented suggestions and https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode, I've tried adding this code to my web.config for a **server rewrite**:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

But now, **absolutely** everything just redirects to the root/home page: `localhost:8885/`.

Any help?

Comment: You are still using angular 1.x? Angular >= 2.x defaults to non-has prefixes and is configured a bit differently. Did you had a look at http://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices? It adds a default/fallback route handling (See example project there) and it can be used for server-sided rendering (first request will be rendered on the server and sent to the browser to reduce the initial loading time, subsequent requests will be done client sided)

Comment: @Tseng I am still using Angular 1.6.4. Would this solution not be possible given that? Am I forced to use Angular >= 2.x ?

Comment: you must configure your server for URL rewrites.  the fine folks that created the module ui-router  provided a very great FAQ on this subject with instructions for all kinds of different servers, including C#.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode.  This will work for any angular router, for 1.x or 2.x.

Comment: @claies I tried your link and implemented the server side code mentioned for `Azure IIS Rewrites`. I put it in my `web.config` file, but unfortunately, every single page redirects to the home page now (`/`). Any help?

Answer (score 1):

#### $location in HTML5 mode requires a `<base>` tag to be present.

via the docs:

> If you configure $location to use html5Mode (history.pushState), you need to specify the base URL for the application with a  tag or configure $locationProvider to not require a base tag by passing a definition object with requireBase:false to $locationProvider.html5Mode():
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

The fix is to update your `$locationProvider` code to this:

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
     enabled: true,
     requireBase: true
 });
```

And then, inside of your `<head>`, set your `<base>` accordingly.
The most common pattern is `/`, but your application might requires assets to be accessed from a different folder.

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

Or, if you want to be clever, like https://plnkr.co does for bootstrapping Angular plunks:

```
<head>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
</head>
```

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect my current implementation, largely reflecting your proposed solution. If you could please either refine your answer or delete it.

Comment: where is your `ui-view`?

Comment: I just made an edit to include the `ui-view` location.

Comment: ui-router populates the element you place the `ui-view` directive on. You shouldn't put anything inside of that div (e.g. `@renderBody()`), as it will get written over...

Comment: So you're saying the solution is to delete the `@renderBody()` call?

Comment: If deleted, I get error message `RenderBody has not been called for the page at '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'. To ignore call IgnoreBody().`. If I replace `@renderBody()` with `@IgnoreBody()`, I get an error in VS saying `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'`. Any suggestions?

Comment: If left in, what is the markup that `@renderBody()` outputs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143903/discussion-between-volcovmeter-and-couzzi).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue with AngulaJS SPA, I could resolve with the following code:

Startup.cs

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                    await next();
                }
            })
            .UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions { DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" } })
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseMvc();
```

Index.html

```
<base href="/" />
```

and while referencing static files under wwwroot folder use a forward slash

```
<script src="/app.js"></script>
<script src="/app/services/auth.service.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
$stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/index.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: "vm"
        });

$locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: true
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/stores');
```

url rewrite in web.config does not work anymore with latest ASP.NET core, you can remove that code from web.config.

if you are using MVC, you can try with the following code, though I haven't

```
        app.UseStaticFiles()
           .UseMvc(routes =>
           {
               routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
               routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
           });
```